# Out of memory exception. May be from webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

I got out of memory exception problem for 4 months. My client use webservice, they wanna me test their webservice. In their webservice, there is a function call upload. I test that function on 1500 users who uploaded at the same time. I tried garbage collection function of visual studio (GC). With 2mb of file, there is not exception, but with 8mb of file there is still out of memory exception. I have tried many times and a lot of solutions but still happened. I gonna crazy now. When upload is on going, I watched memory of all test computers but memory is not out of. So I think that problem is from webservice and server. But my client said that i have to improve those reasons which is from webservice and server to them. I'm gonna crazy now. Do you guys have any solotions for this? In additional, Our client does not public code, I just use webservice's function to test. Additional, I have to use vps to connect their webservice and network rather slow when connect to vps.

I have to make sure that my test script doesn't have any problem. Here is my test script to test upload function.

```
public void UploadNewJob(string HalID, string fileUID, string jobUID, string fileName, out List errorMessages)

{

errorMessages = null;

try

{ 

int versionNumber;

int newVersionNumber;

string newRevisionTag;

datasyncservice.ErrorObject errorObj = new datasyncservice.ErrorObject();

PfgDbJob job = new PfgDbJob();

job.CompanyName = Constant.SEARCH_CN;

job.HalliburtonSalesOffice = Constant.SEARCH_SO;

job.HalliburtonOperationsLocation = Constant.SEARCH_OL;

job.UploadPersonHalId = HalID;

job.CheckOutState = Constant.CHECKOUT_STATE;

job.RevisionTag = Constant.NEW_REVISION_TAG;

var manifestItems = new List();

var newManifestItems = new List();

var manifestItem = new ManifestItem();

if (fileUID == "")

{

if (job.JobUid == Guid.Empty)

job.JobUid = Guid.NewGuid();

if (job.FileUid == Guid.Empty)

job.FileUid = Guid.NewGuid();

}

else

{

Guid JobUid = new Guid(jobUID);

job.JobUid = JobUid;

Guid fileUid = new Guid(fileUID);

job.FileUid = fileUid;

}

// Change the next line when we transfer .ssp files by parts 

manifestItem.PartUid = job.FileUid;

job.JobFileName = fileName;

manifestItem.BinaryFileName = job.JobFileName;

manifestItem.FileUid = job.FileUid;

manifestItem.JobUid = job.JobUid;

manifestItem.PartName = string.Empty;

manifestItem.SequenceNumber = 0;

manifestItems.Add(manifestItem);

errorMessages = DataSyncService.Instance.ValidateForUploadPfgDbJobToDatabase(out newVersionNumber, out newRevisionTag, out errorObj, out newManifestItems, HalID, job, false);

if (manifestItems.Count == 0)

manifestItems = newManifestItems;

if (errorMessages.Count > 0)

{

if (errorMessages.Count > 1 || errorMessages[0].IndexOf("NOT AN ERROR") == -1)

{ 

return;

}

}

//upload new Job 

Guid transferUid;


long a= GC.GetTotalMemory(false);


byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

fileContents = null;

GC.Collect();

long b = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);


//Assert.Fail((b - a).ToString());

//errorMessages = DataSyncService.Instance.UploadFileInAJob(out transferUid, out errorObj, job.UploadPersonHalId, job, manifestItem, fileContents);


DataSyncService.Instance.UploadPfgDbJobToDatabase(out errorObj, out versionNumber, job.UploadPersonHalId, job, false, manifestItems);

}

catch (Exception ex)

{

Assert.Fail("Error from Test Scripts: " + ex.Message);

}

}
```

Please review my test code. And if there is not any problem from my test code, I have to improve reason is not from my test code T_T

Comment: what's the server specification?

Comment: My client use window server 2008, IIS 7, and they host about 4 or 5 webservice on their IIS

Comment: We certainly can't tell you by looking at our crystal ball. You need a debugger. Once you isolate some potential problem sites, [edit] your question to include the actual code.

Comment: I have just edited my question

Comment: no, i mean the hardware.
usually server ran out of memory(ram)

Comment: Intel xeon E5540 2.53 ghz x2
Installed Physical memory (RAM) 24GB
Total virtual memory 48GB

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you hit the 2 GB object size limit of .NET (1500 * 8MB > 4GB).
 
You should consider to change to .NET 4.5 and use the large object mode - see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx)  - the setting is called gcAllowVeryLargeObjects.

Comment: Thanks, my client use 24GB RAM. Does .net framework 3.0 have limit 3gb ram? And  even my client use 24gb ram, does .net framework 3.0 just use 4gb of limit?

Comment: .Net 3.0 limits itself to 4 GB. The additional RAM is not useable for your application, thus you need to upgrade to .Net 4.5 if possible.

Comment: Thanks alot, I will request to my client. Thanks again

Comment: Arggg, Excuse me! Could you please provide some official documents or news about 4GB limited of .net framework 3.0? Because i have to improve to customer if I show them this reason

Comment: The 2 GB object limit is mentioned inside the link. If it is possible I would go the route of upgrading to check if it works.

Comment: The changed limit works - I have had mem issues with large objects and solved it with this setting.